# How do i join given two table in efficient way using sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, ansi-sql

**We are having two tables  A and B. We are trying to summarize both table in a way that it gives following output as listed below :**

**Table A :**

```
Today|  WTD|    MTD|   QtrToDate| YTD|  Description| Ord|   Section| Dept
347271  916887  930606  944525  944465  Dispatched   1   1Sales    1Revenue
625850  2322894 2948744 626020  3574764 OpenOrders   1   1Sales    1Revenue
```

**Table B :**

```
OpenAsOfToday|RestOfCurrMonth|OpportFor Curr.Month|NextMonth&Beyond|TotalNetOpen|description|ord|section|dept
787 0   787 0   787 1EC 8   8OrdersGrouped  1Revenue
159398  94882   254280  0   254280  1IN 8   8OrdersGrouped  1Revenue
```

**After adding both table:**

**Output Table:**

```
Dept|Section|Descriprtion|Today|WTD |MTD|QTD|YTD|OpenAsOfToday|Rest Of Curr. Month|OpportForCurrMonth|NextMonth&Beyond|TotalNetOpen
Revenue1    0Orders (ByOrderDate)   3416589 3416589 3416589 3416589 3416589                 
    1Sales  (Picked,OpenOrders,Dispatched,Invoiced,Samples/Events,Proj. Total)  3416589 3416589 3416589 3416589 3416589                 
Revenue2    Orders  (OrdersTotal)   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    123972  123972  123972  123972  123972
    OrdersGrouped   (CustomerClass) NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    123972  123972  123972  123972  123972
```

Any help would be much appreciated on it.

Comment: Start building your query. Then if it does not work, as here. This is not a "Can you do my work for me?" site, sorry.

Comment: We tried almost all joins across both the table. and it is not working  as per output . hence, We  have written  our  question after repeated try on it.

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , one important step in your question is include what have your tried.

Comment: And next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer faster

Comment: Juan Sir, Thank you so much ,Here onward We would like to follow all steps of  etiquette before to  put my questions.

Answer (score 1):

The basic `join` syntaxis and using alias for each table name

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM table1 as A
INNER JOIN table2 as B
  ON A.common_field = B.common_field
```

Comment: Thank you, When we tried following syntax using alias .We achived desired output